# Stack and Null in C#

Tags: c#, null, stack, nullable

```
public Class MyClass
{
int a;
}

Class Something
{

int Main ()
{

Var c = new MyClass();
c = Null;   //Possible

}

}
```

In C#, Var can only be stored on stack so you have to initialize var as soon as variable is defined because Compiler doesn't know to store Null on Stack.From the above code storing null in c(Var c in Main function of something class) is possible. So, does C# Compiler know how to store null on stack or is there any other explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness

> Var can only be stored on stack

That is not true. What is stored on the stack(in managed code) is value types, while reference types are stored on the heap.
So in your case variable `c` is not stored on the stack, it goes to the heap, and `null` is absolutely allowed.
But there is the case when you can store `null` in value type variable, it's a nullabe value type, which is a struct. You can think of it as stored on the stack.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866346/5589027):

> Structs only go on the temporary memory pool, aka "the stack", when
>   they are local variables or temporaries

In this case, `null` is treated in a special way, as a nullable type with not set flag `hasValue`. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028935/5589027)

Comment: In case it answers your question, you can mark it as answer. I would appreciate that.

Comment: How do i mark it as answer? i am new here and have no idea, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has nothing to do with the stack or heap, and simply relates to the type inference.

In the case of initialising a `Var` to `null`, there's no way for the compiler to infer the intended type of the variable so you need to provide type information.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = null;
```

This will result in an error as the compiler doesn't know which `type` to bound `null` to. You could do something like

```
var c = default(MyClass);
```